# How to Change Color on flatlist selectable item

Tags: react-native

How to change color flat list item color when selected item on flat list ?

I have tried on react native document about flat list but I have question about how to use that document correctly in my code

```
function Item({ id, title, selected, onSelect }) {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => onSelect(id)}
      style={[
        styles.item,
        { backgroundColor: selected ? '#6e3b6e' : '#f9c2ff' },
      ]}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}

class ApplyLeaveScreen extends Component {
const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState(new Map());
  const onSelect = React.useCallback(
    id => {
      const newSelected = new Map(selected);
      newSelected.set(id, !selected.get(id));
      setSelected(newSelected);
    },
    [selected],
  );

  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView>
            <View style={styles.content}>
              <FlatList contentContainerStyle ={{justifyContent:'center', margin:5}}
                renderItem={({ item }) => 
                <Item id={item.id} title={item.title} 
                selected={!!selected.get(item.id)}
                onSelect={onSelect}/>}
                keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                id={item.id}
              />
          </View>
</ScrollView>          
}
```

Comment: Can you share your attempt? What you've tried?

Comment: I have edited question

Comment: Have you tried it without the useCallback hook? I don't think that actually gains you much performance-wise since presumably the input and output value changes every time the callback is called from a button press. Could you also drop a `console.log(selected);` to test if your state is actually updating as expected?